# HTML/JS - Unable to Render HTML while Converting from Markdown

Tags: javascript, html, markdown-it

In this example I'm trying to convert everything in `#fileDisplayArea` to markdown. However, the raw HTML within the `div` is not applied.

```
    <div id="fileDisplayArea"># Title
    Lorem **ipsum** dolor sit amet, *consectetur adipiscing* elit

    <center>Consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget</center>

    In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu.
    </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown-it/10.0.0/markdown-it.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            let md = window.markdownit();
            let txt = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea').innerHTML;
                document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea').innerHTML = md.render(txt);
        </script>
```

Running this code properly converts the markdown elements but the raw HTML is not read and instead shows up in the output. Changing the last instance of `innerHTML` to `innerText` provides the following output:

```
    <p>Lorem <strong>ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, 
    <em>consectetur adipiscing</em> elit</p>
    <p>&lt;center&gt;Consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget&lt;/center&gt;</p>
    <p>In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu.</p>
```

This shows that the less/greater than symbols are being escaped. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `textContent` instead of `innerText` to skip HTML tags or enclose the node in backticks to show it as a code block, but `innerText` will always convert brackets. This happens because the library you’re using watch for strings and you’re trying to convert an HTML node. Also, **there’s no native way to center text** with Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who may stumble across this, I managed to find the solution. Within the documentation for markdown-it, certain options are disabled by default. Being able to implement raw HTML is disabled. To fix this, the html flag needs to be enabled. Replace:

```
    let md = window.markdownit();
```

with the following:

```
    let md = window.markdownit({ 
        html: true, 
    });
```

Comment: It does not work for me. The `>` is still rendered as `&gt;` and `<` as `&lt;`.

Comment: @dudung did you get a fix?